# Fixing bootloader from windows 10 installation on another drive?

Tags: windows-10, bootloader

I used to have a dual boot linux mint / windows 10 setup on my PC, but I recently deleted the entire linux partition, and with it grub. I've tried using the built in windows boot repair from a flash drive, but it just fails. I have a second hard drive which I've wiped and installed another copy of windows 10 on to, and from there I can access the drive with the broken bootloader. How can I repair it?

Comment: You might try a quick fix using system imaging tools such as Macrium Reflect, which can sometimes fix boot issues even if you *have not* made a disk image. http://reflect.macrium.com/help/v5/Rescue_CDs/Fix_Boot_Problems.htm

Comment: [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) without the second hard drive (disconnect it).